# How to implement In-apps purchase in a Kivy App (android)

Tags: android, kivy, in-app-purchase, kivymd, pyjnius

I made an Application I would like to implement in-app purchases into, I researched on this extensively, but to no avail.

The process I'm seeing on how to implement in-app purchases, requires android studio, and I don't know how to run a kivy file in android studio, as I think it is mostly for java and koitlin.

I read somewhere that we'll need `pyjnius` to read java file, as we'll need the java extension to add to our dependencies (I don't even know what this means). Based on what I've read in android studio it's in build.gradle, please remember I'm showing android studio.

**So my questions:**

**1** is there a way I can run kivy on android studio to ease this tedious process, and the countless others like creating an aab. file with window OS?

**2** how will I use `pyjnius`, where will I put the java extension, i.e where is this dependencies, I need to add the java extension to? will it be in my buildozer.spec file??

And lastly my recently questions have been ignored, please no matter the help I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks to you, in advance!!

Comment: `my recently questions have been ignored`:StackOverflow answers are generated by volunteers. Your questions are in a seldom visited path of Android written in Python. If you insist on continuing using Kivy, I would also search for open-source example projects and check github issue tickets. As it seems you are new to s/w dev but drifting into harder areas, I would re-evaluate why Kivy, as it may be easier to convert to a Java/Kotlin app with the tools/tutorials/resources available in the Android ecosystem. Perhaps this [github issue ticket](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/issues/544) helps.

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang I initially choose kivy because of it simple syntax, I've been learning it some time now, it's just difficult for me switch right now, I will eventually, but not now.. Thanks for the github issue.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks again.. A month later my projects are almost ready, I'm learning kotlin, which I'm using to remake my projects.. I picked Kotlin because google made it the official android dev. language.... I made the switch thanks to you..